# What license do I need to enable Einstein in Chat Bot?

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot

I have created a chatbot in my org. I want to enable Einstein for that Einstein chatbot in my org.

Is there any specific license that I need? It looks like before enabling that, the bot will just compare the utterance text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, every org that is an Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer should be able to do 25 Einstein Bot conversations per month for no additional cost. The Service Cloud / Chat / Messaging license does not look to be free.

> Obtain a Service Cloud license and a Chat or Messaging license. Each
> org is provided 25 Einstein Bots conversations per month for each user
> with an active subscription. To make full use of the Einstein Bots
> Performance page, obtain the Service Analytics App.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bots_service_requirements.htm&type=5

Comment: What exactly does an Einstein Bot conversation imply. Is it one bot session. If so, in my developer org I am able to initiate more than 25 sessions for a given chatbot. Please guide where does the 25 conversation limit come into picture.